# Can boto's get_resource_type('s3').Object(bucket_name, key) take wildcards?

Tags: python, boto3, boto

I'm very new to python.  I'm using this library that's using boto like this:

```
def get_key(self, key, bucket_name=None):
    """
    Returns a boto3.s3.Object

    :param key: the path to the key
    :type key: str
    :param bucket_name: the name of the bucket
    :type bucket_name: str
    """
    if not bucket_name:
        (bucket_name, key) = self.parse_s3_url(key)

    obj = self.get_resource_type('s3').Object(bucket_name, key)
    obj.load()
    return obj
```

I'm trying to figure out if that `Object(bucket_name, key)` can take wild cards so that I can download multiple files at once.

I've copied this file and modified it so it prints out `type(resource_type)`, but that just says `<class 'boto3.resources.factory.s3.ServiceResource'>`.  Although I can find the source to that class, it doesn't seem to have an `Object()` method in it so I don't know how to answer my question.

1. How do I find the source code of that `Object()` method?
2. Does `Object(bucket_name, key)` take wild cards?  If no, which method should I be calling instead?

Answer (score 0):

s3 allows you to download 1 object with 1 call. You have to enter the exact key to download any object. 
If you want to download multiple objects you will need to use a loop to list out all of the keys you want to download. You can use [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) to get a list of the all the keys and then filter out the list depending on your conditions. If key matches the condition, call the [get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) API to download the body of the object. Note that both these calls are available on client and not resource.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks.  Do you have an answer to question #1?

Comment: You can find their source code on GitHub. You can also view it in Python library once you install it. https://github.com/boto/boto3/

Comment: Yes, I've been looking through that, but how do I find the `Object()` method in that source code?

Comment: I couldn't find a direct object method. You'll have better luck raising this issue in the boto3 issues section so that a developer of the library can guide you.